# CAN-based higher-layer protocols for plug an play devices

Tags: library, networking, embedded-systems, protocol

I need to connect many embedded devices via CAN bus and I am searching for a high layer library/stack that meet the following requirements:

- Allow up to 100 nodes
- Transmission of large data chunks (>1Mb) for firmware updates - ok to take minutes for transmission
- Pull (mandatory) and push (nice to have) communication
- There are several kinds of nodes that need to be distinguish by the master
- There might by more than one physical master, but they should make up who is the logical master (only one logical master)
- Node identification (might be dynamically assigned IDs)
- Adding and removing nodes during run-time (plug and play)

So far [CANopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) seems to meet most of these requirements, but I would like more suggestions.